# While adding service account, How to verify account is already exist via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am adding a  Windows service account via PowerShell in ADSI.  Below is the Powershell code I am using. But my logic is not working properly. There is some hole in my code.

May I know how to check if the user exists already, if not exists have to add the user orlese need to skip adding the user via PowerShell. Someone please correct my logic below

I am looking forward to hear from you

```js
function AddingPacsTrsutedUser
{
    Write-host "Adding PACS Trusted Service Role account"
    $PacsTrustedUser = get-adobject -filter "samaccountname -like '*Pacs*Trusted*'"
    Write-host "Adding PACS Trusted Service Role account"

    if (!($PacsTrustedUser))
    {
        Write-host "Adding PACS Trusted Service Role account"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators -Members 'PACS Trusted Service Role'
        Write-host "Successfully added."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-host "$($PacsTrustedUser) User appears already.  Skipping."
    }
}
AddingPacsTrsutedUser
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem right now?

Comment: @DSSO21 Only the else part is executing, If part is not executing even though the user is missing. not sure if (!($PacsTrustedUser)) is right.

Comment: anyone have idea ????????

Comment: Your script would add the service account to the Administrators group of the domain controller, basically making it domain admin. That cant be right.

Comment: Give us the output of : get-adobject -filter "samaccountname -like '*Pacs*Trusted*'"

Comment: @DavidTrevor

Hi David,

Thanks for your reply. While I am replying here, I am not able to attach the screenshot in stack overflow. So I have typed the output below.



DistinguishedName                                                Name                  
   
-----------------                                                ----                     
CN=PACS Trusted Service Role,CN=Users,DC=SSI19,DC=isyntax,DC=net PACS Trusted Service Role

I am looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: @DavidTrevor
David I am not expertise like you in PowerShell.  could you please modify my code and post in the comment section. I can use it then. It will be very helpful for me. I am looking forward to hear from you

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do. Also see my first comment. You describe something in your question, but your code does something entirely else. At least that is what it seems to me. Please explain on what machine you are trying to do what.

Comment: @DavidTrevor

Its very simple. 

I am explaining you below

Comment: @David Trevor

I am trying to add PACS Trusted Service Role windows account in ADSI edit for ADLDS instance. Needs to be add in local server (member server), not in domain. I am able to add perfectly with the below powershell comment. Only problem is some time user exist already on that time its making conflict. So we need to create a logic like if the user already exist it have to show output like PACS Trusted Service Role user is already exist. Incase the user is missing, it have to add the PACS Trusted Service Role user with my below powershell comment. thats it.

Comment: @DavidTrevor 

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators -Members 'PACS Trusted Service Role'

Comment: Anyone have idea ?

Comment: I have modified my answer below

Comment: @DavidTrevor

Thanks a lot for your code. means a lot. But I am getting the below error.

Comment: @DavidTrevor

Adding PACS Trusted Service Role account
Add-LocalGroupMember : SSI19\PACS Trusted Service Role is already a member of group 
Administrators.
At line:8 char:9
+         Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member 'PACS Trus ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (Administrators:String) [Add-LocalGroupMembe 
   r], MemberExistsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MemberExists,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemb 
   erCommand

Comment: @DavidTrevor but user not exist in the particular tree

Comment: What do you mean with tree? The error message is very clear. On the machine you are executing the command, the local group "Administrators" already contains the member that you want to add (PACS Trusted Service Role). Did you change anything in my code before running it? Where did you run it?

Comment: @DavidTrevor

I was talking about the below tree david.

> ADSI 
 -> Configuration[localhost 3890]
 -> CN=Roles
 -> CN=Administrators
 -> Right Click -> Properties (CN=Administrators)
-> Member -> Edit
-> Add Windows Account (PACS Trusted Service Role)

Here the user is missing. If I ran only this below comment. Its working,

 Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators -Members 'PACS Trusted Service Role'

Its the local server ADSI edit. Not domain server. It might be added in domain level.

I am looking forward to hear from you

Comment: @jimmyafflick the get-adobject command with the if and else statement works fine in my environment. I still do not get wat the actual problem is. Can you please edit your question and add some more informations?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you further. I again don't understand what you mean and what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @DavidTrevor Thanks David. your logic working as expected. Marked your answer as right answer.

Comment: @DavidTrevor David how to mark your answer as right answer ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commends you told me that your AD query...

```
 $PacsTrustedUser = get-adobject -filter "samaccountname -like '*Pacs*Trusted*'"
```

... returns a result. Your if statement checks the if $PacsTrustedUser is empty.

```
if (!($PacsTrustedUser)) {...}
```

Since your query returned a result, $PacsTrustedUser is **not** empty (it contains the object that you wrote in the comments above). Therefore the if statement evaluates to false, going straight to the else block.

From your explanation in the comments above, I understand that you want to add a service account, which is an Active Directory user, to the local administrator groups of different servers.

Your code in your initial question used the cmldets "Get-ADObject" and "Add-ADGroupMember". These commands cannot be used to query or set local group information. Instead try the modified code below, which actually modifies the local administrator group on the server. Your initial code would have added members to the administrator group on the domain controller, this would be very bad in terms of security and not what you want at all.

The modified code below must run on the server where you want to add the user to local admin group.

```
function AddingPacsTrustedUser
{
    $PacsTrustedUser = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DOMAIN\PACS Trusted Service Role'}

    if (!($PacsTrustedUser))
    {
        Write-host "Adding PACS Trusted Service Role account"
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member 'DOMAIN\PACS Trusted Service Role'
        Write-host "Successfully added."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-host "'$($PacsTrustedUser.Name)' appears already. Skipping."
    }
}
AddingPacsTrustedUser
```